# amChartjs grid manually specify value of the distance between two points on the axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I have a chart on my page and I want to make it respond to user input to show variations on changing the gap between two points on the axis , something like

[image: My current results]

so far I have tried using `valueAxis.x = my desired value`

but it does not change the graph.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set autogridCount to false

```
valueAxis.autoGridCount=false;
```

then you need to use

```
valueAxis.gridCount = no of grid lines;
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s4aLmg7/)

Comment: this works but It returns same display output for 5 and 10.

Comment: I observe that when I change values above 30 as well, maybe that has something to do with the interval in the data being provided.